# How can two applications read from the same (digital) sound input in Linux/ALSA?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have a sound card with an AES/EBU input port that I want to access with two applications simultaneously. I want to record the input to a linear WAV file in real-time while also streaming it through IceCast. If I naively try to access the same input device with both applications one tells me that it can't access the device. How can I set up ALSA in order to accomplish this? Or do I have to relay it through some external program, introducing delays?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `dsnoop` plugin to copy the sample data to multiple virtual capture devices.

Put something like this into your `~/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf`, and use `snooped_digital` as device name in both applications:

```perl
pcm.snooped_digital {
    type dsnoop
    slave {
        pcm "hw:2,1"   # the actual device
        channels 2
        rate 48000
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't show up on `arecord -l`. Do you know how to make `snooped_digital` show up on `arecord -l`?

Comment: @felipeduque `hint.description "blah"`